# Por que não usar um Container de Aplicação como o JBoss quando se usa o Spring?

Tags: java, java-ee, spring, jboss, glassfish

Sempre que se discute o uso do Spring juntamente com JBoss ou outro `container`, os profissionais tendem a questionar porque usar um `container` de aplicações JEE.

Então me pergunto, por que não usar? Seria deselegante adotar o melhor dos dois mundos? É uma questão puramente cultural? Ou são realmente concorrentes?

Comment: Quem votou contra, tanto na questão quanto nas respostas, e nem justificou deve ser da Oracle rs

Comment: @BrunoCésar Há 4 votos para fechar como "principalmente baseada em opiniões". Não vou votar para fechar no entanto porque gostei bastante da resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa tranquilo, eu concordo que é baseado em opiniões, até deixei claro na resposta. A questão é a cultura de votar contra e não falar o porque, mas enfim, obrigado.

Comment: @BrunoCésar Pois é. Por isso que eu abri [essa campanha no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2693/132) em abril. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É uma pergunta em que as respostas serão baseadas em opiniões e a minha não é diferente. Não sou xiita e não tenho problemas em usar uma ou outra ou até mesmo ambas quando necessário então vou tentar expor alguns *porques*, tentando contribuir e sei que de longe não é a resposta correta, até por que não existe uma correta, ao meu ver.

Deixo claro que minha preferência é por ferramentas do `Spring` e que muitas vezes as utilizei em conjunto com tecnologias puramente `JEE`, como `EJB` no *backend* e `Spring MVC`, não tenho problema em trabalhar com nenhuma delas se o ambiente me obrigar a algo e tento ser imparcial (mesmo não sendo).

Quanto aos seus questionamento, tentaria pontuar algumas coisas quanto a cada um deles. Então vamos lá!!

> Então me pergunto porque não usar?

De forma curta, por que simplesmente não precisa e por que não justifica.

Se sua aplicação não tem nada que depende um *container* `JEE` não há motivo nenhum para usá-lo se você pode utilizar um `Jetty`, um `Tomcat` ou qualquer coisa assim.

Mas se você já tem um `JBoss`, um `Weblogic`, vá em frente também, nada impede você implantar num *container* `JEE`, não é mesmo?

> Seria deselegante adotar o melhor dos dois mundos?

Para responder com mais exatidão e até mesmo melhor elaborar minha opinião seria interessante um cenário.

Por exemplo, se você está construindo algo do *zero* e quer adotar tecnologias do `Spring` realmente não faz muito sentido você utilizar um *container* `JEE`, já que *servlets containers* vão lhe atender sem problema nenhum.

> É uma questão puramente cultural?

Talvez. Como seres humanos (as vezes pensantes) temos nossas preferências, convicções, etc., basta observar os *evangelizadores* da Oracle em eventos de tecnologia para vermos que eles falam que `JEE` é melhor simplesmente por que é melhor e ponto. O mesmo acontece com algumas pessoas quanto ao Spring, mesmo que menos.

> Ou são realmente concorrentes?

Quanto a este ponto podemos sim considerar concorrência. O `Spring` nasceu basicamente devido a necessidade do mundo corporativo de um framework/plataforma que evoluísse de forma rápida e que estivesse sempre em sintonia com as inovações tecnológicas.

É sabido que no `JEE` as melhorias demoram um bocado a acontecer, veja o quanto demorou até ter algo para `IoC` na plataforma, algo *decente* para segurança, processamento em *batch* e integração. Além disso, muitas das tecnologias hoje existentes no mundo `JEE` só aconteceram por *pressão* do `Spring` e da comunidade que queria que os mantenedores acompanhassem o que estava acontecendo no mercado.

Alguns pontos de concorrência que podemos citar são:

- Spring MVC vs. JSF
- Spring MVC REST/REST Template vs. JAX-RS
- Spring WS vs. JAX-WS
- Spring AOP/AspectJ vs. Interceptor
- etc.

Mesmo havendo concorrência nestes pontos citados, alguns são recentes, já que demorou a aparecer no `JEE`, mas já era algo comum no `Spring`.

Devido a características de como as duas plataformas seguem é mais simples algo acontecer no `Spring` do que no `JEE`. Se você precisa de integração social verá que a [JSR 357: Social Media API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=357) na época foi rejeitada pelo `JCP` e isto existe no Spring já tem um bom tempo e, novamente, tudo *DEPENDE*.

Obviamente existem *religiosos* que vão defender um outro com unhas e dentes, exatamente por ser muito baseado em opinião isto. Para os *evangelizadores* da Oracle para `JEE` falar que `Spring` é o padrão corporativo *de facto* é um heresia, mas de fato o `Spring` se tornou um padrão corporativo, justamente devido aos avanços dele, de responder a mudanças de forma rápida e prática.

Veja algumas boas discussões e conteúdo sobre isto:

- [Java EE versus Spring: retomando a discussão](http://blog.caelum.com.br/java-ee-versus-spring-retomando-a-discussao/)
- [Java EE and Spring Side-by-Side](http://pt.slideshare.net/reza_rahman/java-ee-and-spring-sidebyside-34320697) - veja os comentários também, é uma briga que só rs
- [Why is Java EE 6 better than Spring ?](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/why_java_ee_6_is) - aqui você vê como o pessoal da Oracle fala, já que ganham pra isso =)

**Conclusão (????)**

Você pode muito bem utilizar frameworks do Spring e fazer a implantação da sua aplicação em containers `JEE`, nada impede você de fazer isto. No entanto, caso sua aplicação não dependa de nada de um container `JEE`, como `EJB`, não há justificativa para isto uma vez que você pode utilizar apenas *servlets containers*, novamente sempre que você puder decidir isto. Você pode implantar nos ambientes, veja que um cliente seu pode ter já uma infra com *container* `JEE`, aí o que já não justifica é você pedir para ele instalar um `Jetty` da vida só para você. O contrário também vale, não é mesmo?

Ainda hoje o arcabouço Spring é superior, vide suporte a plataformas `NoSQL` e outras inovações como o [`Spring Session`](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/) ou [`Spring Cloud`](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) e procure a data de lançamento do `JEE`8 =/

Quando posso escolher as tecnologias que irei utilizar prefiro sempre utilizar as do Spring. Veja como é mais simples publicar serviços, implementar APIs com conceitos como `HATEOAS`, e os repositórios do spring data, que nem preciso implementar as consultar e se quiser posso expor serviços a partir deles de forma simples ([Spring Data REST](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/))?

Um outro ponto não citado ainda e que o `Spring` *ganha* é o fato de que ele nunca negou em adotar as boas tecnologias do mercado, sendo do mundo `JEE` ou não. `JPA` surgiu, `Spring` foi lá e deu um jeito de suportar e facilitar ainda mais seu uso. `CDI` apareceu, o *container IoC* do `Spring` dá suporte ao padrão de anotações dele, mas trabalha de forma diferente, principalmente quanto ao `C` do `CDI`. Suporte a `JSF`, `JMS`, `JAX-RS` (mais ou menos) também estão presentes no `Spring`, sem contar outros aspectos.

O que temos que saber é: usemos o que melhor pudermos de acordo com a situação, mas sempre buscando pela simplicidade, por algo que vá nos atender.

Enfim, é uma longa discussão...

Comment: Obrigado Bruno! muito positivo suas colocações!
Estarei lendo os links sugeridos, por hora você me respondeu o que perguntei.

Answer (score 0):

Não é que não deve ou não pode. Mas é algo parecido com instalar o Windows no seu notebook, e dentro do Windows uma máquina virtual com Linux, e usar a máquina virtual Linux para tudo. Então toda vez que quiser usar o Linux você terá que iniciar o sistema operacional Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Não faz sentido querer trazer complexidade para o que é simples e plenamente funcional. Geralmente quem usa Spring preza pela genial simplicidade.